# Linking external JS to rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, hyperlink

This should be a simple one but I cant get the syntax quite right.

I also cant find any examples of externally linked files, All search results I've found seem to solve their problems by storing a local copy of the file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is a simple external script tag in my .erb file but rails is not picking up anything that isnt using

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'whatever.js' %>
```

How do I externally link up a JS to my rails app.

I cannot store the Jquery.js locally due to technical requirements (I don't understand it either)

---

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' %>
```

Perhaps the problem wasnt me not referencing the file correctly. It seems to be generated in the html.erb file fine but in the firebug console, I'm getting Jquery not defined.

```
jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error] remText=remText.replace(/\%n/g,charsRe...al:true,allowExceed:false};})(jQuery);
jquery...9702940 (line 17)
jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error] })(jQuery); 
protot...0469242 (line 5653)
```

---

The generated HTML links.
I have no idea why the standard src = tag wont find it.

```
     <link href="/stylesheets/globalStyleSheet.css?1312383253" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/jquery.inputlimiter.1.0.css?1312464674" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/style.css?1312469715" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link href="/stylesheets/globalStyleSheet.css?1312383253" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/style.css?1312469715" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/jquery.inputlimiter.1.0.css?1312464674" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/globalStyleSheet.css?1312383253" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.inputlimiter.1.0.css?1312464674" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/style.css?1312469715" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.inputlimiter.1.2.2.min.js?1299702940" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/globalviewFunctions.js?1312381897" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/javascripts/editInPlace.js?1312468960" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/errorDisplay.js?1312381897" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/journeyViewFunctions.js?1312541017" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/pageviewFunctions.js?1312449379" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/shaneShowHide.js?1312387899" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/Legacy.js?1312381897" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/editInPlace.js?1312468960" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/errorDisplay.js?1312381897" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/globalviewFunctions.js?1312381897" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/journeyViewFunctions.js?1312541017" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/jquery.inputlimiter.1.2.2.min.js?1299702940" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js?1312544046" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/pageviewFunctions.js?1312449379" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/shaneShowHide.js?1312387899" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1310469242" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Adding the absolute path to an external file should pull it in as usual. Is jquery.js actually being loaded? What does the <script> tag look like when the page renders? Are you loading prototype as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my applications I also use the [`javascript_include_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag) to include javascripts. Only difference is that I feed it an array (which gets dynamically filled). It works somethin like this:

```
def add_javascript(url)
  @javascript_urls ||= []
  @javascript_urls << url unless @javascript_urls.include?(url)
end

def create_javascript_urls()
  javascript_include_tag(@javascript_urls) + "\n" unless @javascript_urls.blank?
end
```

To add the jQuery javascript I use:

```
add_javascript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js')
```

It all seems similar to me compared to your question examples, but maybe it helps you in finding the answer...

Comment: So I take it the standard src = "httpblaghblahblah" should have worked. Any ideas why it might not?

Comment: Added a link to the docs in my answer, but I suppose you already found it. I cannot see why it is not working... Maybe one of the other scripts is interfering? Try to remove the others and see whether the jQuery is working (if possible) and gradually put the others back.

Comment: And... I see thet the jQuery script is loaded later than some of the plugin scripts. I do not know for sure, but might that pose a problem?

Comment: Spot on! That solved the Jquery not defined problem but unfortunately the others are still there. namely element.dispatchEvent is not a function, Also $ was being overwritten by proto I think

Comment: I guess it would be best to start a new question for that problem if you cannot solve it. So you can reformulate the problem with the new details, make sure you show example of the revvelant code pieces and restulting HTML! ;) Good luck!

Comment: The problem was infact the configuration of rails. In the javascript include all part. It was adding a bunch of javascript files that seemed to conflict with JQuery. So i removed them. No need for another question as you put me on the path to finding that very simple answer.